# Removing UIButtons setBackroundImage Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to remove the images that I've loaded into buttons using

```
button1.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIControlState.Normal);
```

and I get an error because I can't set it to null and thats the only way I could possibly think of clearing it. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

I've tried doing a FromFile("", Controlstate.Normal), also creating a UIImage and setting that to null and then setting it etc. For some reason I can set the image of a UIImage to null but I can't set the background on the on the button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you not just swap the button out with a new one with no bg image?

Comment: just new up a new button - remove the existing one, add the new one, null out the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty image and use that instead.

```
button1.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIControlState.Normal);
```